# Where can I ask Android related questions in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know where I can ask Android apps and other mobile related questions. Is there a Stack Exchange site for such questions?

Comment: What **kind** of question? There is [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/), but you need to read their help center to see what is and is not on-topic there.

Comment: Android application related. for example. is there any sms forwarding or disabling application available for android ?

Comment: I don't know if [android.se] accepts this kind of question - read their help center. If they don't I doubt there is any Stack Exchange site that will. We tend to find recommendation questions to be unsuitable for our format.

Comment: You might find [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289) useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

If it is about Android programming, try Stack Overflow.

If it is about using Android, see [android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Check out their [about](https://android.stackexchange.com/about) and [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/ontopic) first, though. App recommendation questions are off topic though, however the associated chat rooms may be able to help.

Comment: Well-formed app recommendation requests should be okay for [softwarerecs.se].